# How to use の如く.

Tags: grammar

> 集められた魔力、剥離された精神が残留し、**山は禿げ山の如く訪れたモノを食らうだろう**。
>
> Gathered Magic, The separated souls stay behind, The mountain eats those that visit, just like a bald mountain.

I have trouble understanding 如く.
I know it's an adverb and it means=Similar
But, I do not think it's modifying 訪れたモノ.
I think that it could be rewritten like this:

> 山は,禿げ山の如く,訪れたモノを食らうだろう。

Am I wrong?

Comment: I think it's modifying 訪れたモノを食らう.

Comment: How would I translate it though?

Comment: I would translate 如く as "just like" as you did.

Comment: As an adverb, 如く modifies the verb -- so, just as you surmise, it _can't_ modify 訪れたモノ, since that's a noun.  FWIW, 如く is the adverbial form of adjective 如き (the classical attributive form that attaches to a noun, like modern -い adjectives), and it's also sometimes seen with the classical terminal ending (end-of-sentence ending) 如し.  Kinda like べく・べき・べし, this is a kind of -い adjective that has fossilized (remains in use in the modern language, but with older forms).

Comment: What? Why is 訪れたモノ a noun? I mean, Why does not modify  訪れた which modifies モノ?

Comment: 訪れたモノ is a noun phrase, more specifically.  In terms of pure grammatical function, 禿げ山の如く _could_ modify 訪れた, but semantically, that doesn't make sense: mountains don't visit (bald or otherwise), not even within the metaphorical senses of this particular sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「[如]{ごと}く」 is an auxiliary verb, not an adverb, but since it is in the [連用形]{れんようけい}, it ***functions*** adverbially.  (The dictionary form is 「如し」, of course.)

「～～の如く」 means 「～～のように」, expressing how similar one thing is to another.

> 「山は[禿]{は}げ山の如く[訪]{おとず}れたモノを[食]{く}らうだろう」
>
> = "The mountain, just like a bald mountain, will devour all who visit it."

「禿げ山の如く」 modifies 「食らう」 here.

> "I think that it could be rewritten like this:
>
> 山は,禿げ山の如く,訪れたモノを食らうだろう。
>
> Am I wrong?"

It ***could*** be if you insisted, but why would you? Basically, no one would be confused by this sentence without the commas.

Comment: Could it in no way modify 訪れた? Is it just because it makes no sense or because of other reasons?

Comment: I know that JA-JA dictionaries list 如し as a 助動詞, but do you have any idea why?  I find this categorization quite curious.  In terms of conjugation, it's a classical し・き・く adjective.